# Emscripten code and three.js

Tags: c++, c, three.js

I would like, if it's possible, to use Emscripten code generated from C/C++ with the Javascript library three.js. For example, from emscripten code I want to pass rendering information to the three.js that will be showed in the browser.

So, can someone give me an idea of how to do that?

Comment: I'd go the other way around, use a C/C++ engine that can be "compiled" to Javascript, and use WebGL for rendering. [Unity 5 for instance should be able to do that very soon](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/04/29/on-the-future-of-web-publishing-in-unity/). But I don't think there's any open source engine supporting that for the moment.

Comment: Looks like there's some attempts to port Ogre 3D: https://github.com/joeyview/ogre/wiki/document, for instance. Also, check this ticket: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/485.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple ways to interact from c++ to javascript. I can show you one way I find quite handy:

in the [js library file](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/coding/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html?highlight=library)

```
// here you write JS "handlers"
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {

   new_cube: function(size, color) {
      var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
         new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size),
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color })
      );
   }

});
```

in c++

```
extern "C" {
    extern void new_cube(const int size, const char* color);
}

int main() {
  new_cube(10, "red");
  return 1;
}
```

in the build command

```
emcc source.cpp --js-library src/library.js
```

for easy debugging (but very slow)

```
#include <emscripten.h>
void emscripten_log(const char* string, bool escape = true)
{
    char buff[1024];
    sprintf(buff, (escape ? "console.log('%s');" : "console.log(%s);"), string);
    emscripten_run_script(buff);
}
void emscripten_debugger()
{
    emscripten_run_script("debugger");
}
```